# In a linear regression, why is the mean of all $y_i$ equal to 0?

Tags: regression, covariance, expected-value, independence

[image]

I don't understand why the mean for all $y_i$s must equal $0$.
What property/properties does the above assertion rely on?
I had thought that the mean of $y_i=E(y_i)$, so:

$$
E(y_1)=\alpha
$$

$$
E(y_2)=\alpha+\beta
$$

$$
E(y_3)=\alpha+\gamma
$$

$$
E(y_4)=\alpha+\beta+\gamma
$$

Since:

1. $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are constants
2. The mean of $\epsilon_i$'s are 0, as provided by the question.

Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see anything that establishes the y's have mean 0

Comment: @Glen_b thanks for having a look at my question. I've provided the whole solution to the problem. There is actually two methods to arrive at the answer. Is it possible to arrive at the answer ($-\frac{1}{2}$) without assuming the all the y's have mean 0?

Comment: Method 1 is plainly wrong concerning the expectations of the $y_i$.  In fact you can work out algebraically that $\mathbb{E}(\hat\alpha\hat\beta) = \alpha\beta-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @whuber could you please show me how you worked out $E(\hat{\alpha}\hat{\beta})$? I am stuck at the part with the curly braces. Do I expand them or can they be further simplified first?

Comment: Substitute the definitions and use the linearity of expectation. For instance, the first term within the curly braces is $\mathbb{E}(y_1y_2)=\mathbb{E}\left((\alpha+\epsilon_1)(\alpha+\beta+\epsilon_2)\right)$, which you expand algebraically into terms like $\mathbb{E}(\alpha^2)=\alpha^2$, $\mathbb{E}(\alpha\epsilon_2)=\alpha\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_2)=0,$ and $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_1\epsilon_2)$ (plus others of similar forms). The latter is $\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_1)\mathbb{E}(\epsilon_2)=0$ due to independence of the $\epsilon_i$. Evidently, your text is confusing the $y_i$ with the $\epsilon_i$.